# Logitech F310 gamepad's setup ignored by games

Tags: games, logitech, gamepad

I have setup `logitech F310` gamepad according to [this](http://nomoreterminals.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-set-up-logitech-f310-on-ubuntu.html) site.

It looks OK, when I run `jstest-gtk`, but when I run the game `Xonotic` the
gamepad is ignored.

I tried:

`export SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0`

and then run in the same terminal window

`./xonotic-linux-sdl.sh`

which didn't help

I set:

```
> sudo chmod 777 /dev/input/js0
> ls -la /dev/input/js0
> crwxrwxrwx+ 1 root input 13, 0 Oct 14 15:57 /dev/input/js0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same F310 and it works with Xonotic 0.8.2 (downloaded from the website) on Ubuntu 18.04 after turning on the setting labeled **use joysyik input** on the **other** section on the **input** setting. Also the joystick need to be in the "X" position.

I'm hoping this solves your problem

P.S. The default joystick mapping seems to be strange

[image: Input setting]

Comment: I overlooked this settings :-) But there seems to be other problem, when I press certain button, the character is turning left and I can't stop it.